# Using the Firebase security rules, how could I prevent a user from taking an action (e.g., upvoting a post) more than once?

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am trying to create a Reddit/Hacker News-like voting system on "posts" that users submit. I don't want to allow a user to vote for the same post more than once. What's the best way to prevent users from doing this using Firebase's security API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A simple voting system: how to prevent duplicate votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16863272/a-simple-voting-system-how-to-prevent-duplicate-votes)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Kato -- I somehow missed that one. I think it would still be interesting to see how to count the "likes" users have added to a particular post (see comments in Alex Ghisculescu answer below). Any thoughts/ideas? It may be that numChildren() is the way to go for now, and we can deal with a situation where there are thousands of votes later.

Comment: In a situation where there are thousands of votes, just increment a counter every time a vote is recorded. I covered that as part of this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971571/how-do-i-prevent-duplicate-voting-while-incrementing-the-vote-count-on-firebase

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to have a location for each post, and then children for user IDs that have liked the post. eg. `https://<you>.firebaseio.com/posts/<post_id>` and `https://<you>.firebaseio.com/posts/<post_id>/likes/<user_id>`.

Then, you could have a `.validate` rule that, when attempting to add push a new like to the list, first checks if `https://<you>.firebaseio.com/posts/<post_id>/likes` has that child already. So the rule would look like: (note: not tested)

```
"likes": {
  ".validate": "!data.hasChildren([newData.val()])",
},
```

(Happy to hear if there is a better way of doing this out there!)

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but how would you then get the overall count of the "likes" in this sort of system?

Comment: Also, you might be able to write the rule like this (also untested):
"likes": {
  "$user": {
    ".write": "auth.uid == $user",
    ".validate": "!data.exists()"
 }
}

Comment: I suppose to answer my first question/comment, you could pull into the client the list of all the users who "liked" the post and do a count on it client-side. I worry that if the list got very long (i.e., if the site was like Reddit big) it would impact performance... but until then, the answer is "good enough." I would still be curious to see if there's a smart way to do it with a likes number stored somewhere so you don't have to do all this counting client-side.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-of-children-of-a-node-w-out-loading-all - not looking too promising at the moment.